# Something took control over Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

So I was using Notepad++ today and then all of a sudden I couldn't move my mouse or keyboard but there was this message that was being typed out in a new page on Notepad, it was about the freedom of speech then it said Je Suis Charlie.

Do I have a virus on my system or malware that is allowing someone to control the computer?  I'm really scared because I had no idea what was going on.

Comment: It can arguably be considered malware because it does something unannounced, but it's a part of Notepad++ and only affects that program. As long as you don't mind having your software hijacked by its developer for a political message (whether you support that message or not [I do]), then there's no reason to worry. If you don't support political hijacks, I suggest you look into a Notepad++ alternative, as the developer continues to defend the right do include such hijacks under "freedom of speech."

Comment: @trlkly: Uhm. Many programs have "unannounced" features.

Comment: @trlkly I still worry. Not because of the actual political statement but because of the unusual way of presenting it and how the developer(s) handled the situation. They added a feature that looks like a virus and caused fear or confusion among users. This feature caused huge costs, I've heard about poor network admins flooded with support requests, having to do security audits. The real issue: Will this happen again? I can't find any apologies or indications that it won't. In my opinion this shows incompetence on part of the developers and makes it a risk to use n++ in the future.

Comment: @kapep "Apologies"? Maybe this wasn't the best choice of update, but the discussion is getting hyperbolic. Can I remind you that **notepad++ is free** and basically exists because of the **generosity of Don Ho** and the other contributors. **If you have enterprise specific needs you really have to cough up or shut up.**

Comment: @NathanCooper I really respect the work of the developers and contributers, they invested much to provide a great free software! N++ is one of the most popular editors though, don't they also have _some_ responsibility, even if it is free? I can only guess, but based on many complaints I've seen, there might have been thousands of users thinking they have been hacked. If they do whatever they want because n++ is free, I loose trust in the project. So, maybe no "apologize", but I'd expect that they at least acknowledge the negative effects they caused (and hopefully promise not to do it again)

Comment: @kapep It's their software, they can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: @Th0masR0ss Of course they can. I actually didn't mean to complain that they do, it's probably the reason the n++ got so popular. Maybe I (and many others too) are overreacting about a single "feature" that went a bit wrong. It's just that - from a high quality project - I would expect some statement about the situation. Of course they don't _have_ to give a statement or do anything. If they don't, then maybe the project just isn't as high quality as I thought.

Comment: @kapep [they](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.7.4-je-suis-charlie-edition.html) [did](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/hacking-npp-site.html)

Comment: @Th0masR0ss Thanks, it seems I missed the relevant part "The automatic typing [...] is a feature. Sorry for the panic." when I first read it.

Comment: do you know how to make it come again? coz i was half way reading it and closed my other tab and it just stopped. it was cool.

Comment: No it's not a virus, rather is the author of the app that feels a need to involve his political views into his app. Because of this statement I have stopped using notepad++ for years and also encourage other developers to do the same.

Comment: To prevent link rot: @user246682 's link was moved by the page's author to https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/npp-site-hacked-cos-je-suis-charlie-edition/
I have more I wish to say but [nhinkle had a good point](https://superuser.com/questions/868181/something-took-control-over-notepad#comment1154121_868185).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Notepad++ had a "Je suis Charlie" edition (6.7.4) that would type this automatically post install . . .

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.7.4-je-suis-charlie-edition.html

Comment: I have removed argumentative comments that did not address the question of "what is going on with Notepad++". This answer explains exactly why the behavior the question-asker observed occurred. If you are interested in debating the morality of the situation, I suggest you [create a chat room to do so](http://chat.superuser.com), or better yet, take it up with the developers of Notepad++ directly. **Please keep all future comments focused on the question.** Off-topic questions will be deleted, and the post may be locked if arguments continue.

Comment: I was just showing a coworker that they should use notepad++ and not notepad (MS) when opening an HTML file.  That message came up and started typing, and my coworker looked at me like "what the heck weird stuff are you installing on my computer".

Answer (score 26):

I will just add to the existing answers that your *entire computer* was not being taken over - it may have looked that way, but it's actually just a typing animation. You retain control while it's happening.

I updated to that version and got about half-way through watching the "typing" then closed the tab and continued on my merry way. My mouse and keyboard were not locked at all.

It's basically just a way of drawing extra attention to a post-install message.

Comment: This is a rather important detail.

Comment: It was just so sudden that I thought someone actually took control of the mouse and the keyboard since the mouse moved and it started typing.  It's good to know it's not a virus

Answer (score 8):

Adding to ernie's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/868185/352136), you can use the previous version:

> If you don't like "Je suis Charlie" edition, that's fine. You can still use Notepad++ v6.7.3 - they are the same in terms of features and bug fixes.

From a [developer newspost](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/v674-je-suis-charlie-edition/).

Comment: Except it's an automatic update, so you really can't.

Comment: Where do you see it as automatic? I just did a clean install of 6.7.3 and on startup it [suggests updating](http://i.imgur.com/O0BcfCM.png).

Comment: And if you don't agree, it will suggest that every time you start, unless you turn off updates altogether. Perhaps technically "automatic update" is too strong a word, but I've seen it used for nag updates as well. Windows, for example, still calls it "automatic updates" if I choose to have it wait until I tell it to install things. My point is, he deliberately tries to make it hard for you to use a non-hijacked version.

Comment: This is called an *automatic update check*. As nhinkle [said](http://superuser.com/questions/868181/something-took-control-over-notepad#comment1154121_868185), this is not the place to discuss or criticise the update.